# How can Geordi see screens?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, technology

Geordi La Forge's visor can be used to see different electromagnetic fields. This lets him see people as glowing fields, as well as other fields. How can he see monitors and other interfaces? A screen would have to have variance in its field in order to differentiate the separate icons so that his visor could pick it up but they don't do this (or at least real screens don't). Is there any in-universe explanation?

Comment: [Van Eck Phreaking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Eck_phreaking) :)?

Comment: @DVK you beat me by 14 seconds +1!

Comment: _"A screen would have to have variance in its field in order to differentiate the separate icons so that his visor could pick it up but they don't do this (or at least real screens don't)."_ Not sure what you think colours are!!

Comment: Related, not dupe: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/96385/how-does-geordi-laforges-visor-work

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Geordi's visor detects electromagnetic emissions - visible light is a part of the electromagnetic spectrum. It's just that the visor picks up a wider range of frequencies than natural human eyes can.

He'll still be able to distinguish icons, text and graphics on a screen that is active, just like we can.

Comment: Another way to put it is that what he sees is a superset of what normal human eyes see, so he can see whatever we see -- plus a lot more.

Comment: I thought that this particular part of the spectrum was unavailable to him (since this has formed a few plot-lines before), but you raise a valid point.

Comment: I don't remember anything about the visible spectrum being unavailable (and you'd think this would be a pretty bad prosthetic if it was) - just that he's never seen anything without the rest of the spectrum, meaning he's never seen things as a 'normal' human would have.

Comment: If I were Geordi I would have modified the screens of the Enterprise to interface directly with my visor, so that I could get more information from them.